# Dimension of minimal face

Tags: convex-analysis

So I'd like to know how all nonempty minimal faces of $C$ have the same dimension ($C$ is a closed convex set).

In fact, how is it equal to the dimension of the lineality space lin$(C)$.

Please help!

Comment: please provide context for this qn.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.